# Vue Composition API: 2-way binding with conversion independent of components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Given a reactive structured object value `rgb = ref<RgbColor>({ r:0, g:0, b:0 })`, I want to create another value `hsv` from it that

- when the attributes of `rgb` (`r`, `g`, `b`) are changed, the value of `hsv` is recomputed (doesn't have to be instantly, but at the latest when `hsv` is read)
- when the attributes of `hsv` (`h`, `s`, `v`) are changed, the value of `rgb` is recomputed (doesn't have to be instantly, but at the latest when `rgb` is read)
- of course an infinite loop of circular updates must be prevented
- I want to be able to define all of this using only the Composition API and not have to depend on the existence of actual Vue components (don't abuse a component just to be able to use `v-model`)

My first approach was using a writable computed ref, like this:

```
const hsv = computed<HsvColor>({
  get: () => {
    return convert('rgb', 'hsv', rgb.value)
  },
  set(v) {
    rgb.value = convert('hsv', 'rgb', v)
  }
})
```

(Note: TypeScript type definition and back-and-forth conversion implementation are not included as they are irrelevant for the question.)

This approach doesn't work as desired, because the reactivity is only shallow.
Once an attribute of `hsv` is updated (i.e. `hsv.v = 100`) the setter of the computed ref is not triggered.

One naïve/manual approach comes to mind:

1. create a new `hsv = ref({ h:0, s:0, v:0 })` (or alternatively `reactive(...)`)
2. introduce 2 boolean locks `rgbChanging` and `hsvChanging`
3. watch both `rgb` and `hsv` with `{ deep: true, flush: 'sync' }` such that they

   1. bail out if the lock of the other value is true
   2. set their own lock to `true`
   3. perform the conversion and write the other value
   4. set their own lock to `false`

This defining of boolean lock variables strikes me as ugly/hacky and I would like to avoid it.
Could this be done more elegantly with the existing API?

Comment: `hsv.v =` - shouldn't ever happen with a computed. Means that's the case for a watcher. I'm not sure you need locks, flush sync could eliminate a need for them.

Comment: `hsv.v = 100` is incorrect, anyway. Even for a writable computed, you still use `.value`: `hsv.value.v = 100` .

Comment: I have implemented the approach with `reactive` instead of refs - no `hsv.value` necessary in that case. However I don't see why sync would eliminate the need for locks - if anything it would trigger the infinite update-cycle instantly instead of going over the queues

Comment: If it helps, VueUse has [`watchIgnorable`](https://vueuse.org/shared/watchIgnorable/), which you could use instead of implementing the locks yourself. Or, tada: [`syncRef`](https://vueuse.org/shared/syncRef/): Two-way refs synchronization with the capability for custom transforms. You don't have to actually use that if this is a "learning experience"; you can simply study the code. It does indeed use a pair of watchers, as Estus said.

Comment: @IARI Does using a library "invalidate" an answer? Else I could try extract all those functions into a standalone implementation. I'll wait for confirmation before writing up an answer.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Maybe someone finds this question does not have VueUse in their project and wands to avoid additional dependencies - in that case I can see benefit of an answer that also includes at least references to the particular source files, or better yet, code excerpts from there.
I actually decided to use VueUse in the project a short while ago - so since its included already anyways, I would accept an answer that just uses the VueUse implementation.

Comment: I'll write up an answer that shows how using VueUse, with references to the sources. If I have time, I'll include a standalone version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### VueUse utility

The excellent [VueUse library](https://vueuse.org/) has a [`syncRef` function](https://vueuse.org/shared/syncRef/), which provides bidirectional syncing of refs (or, optionally, just left-to-right or right-to-left) with the capability for custom transforms.

The following is an example of how you could use this for your problem:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { syncRef } from '@vueuse/core'

import { convert } from 'some-package' // I don't know where your `convert` function comes from.

const rgb = ref<RgbColor>({ r:0, g:0, b:0 })
const hsv = ref<HsvColor>(convert('rgb', 'hsv', rgb.value))

const stopSyncing = syncRef(rgb, hsv, {
  transform: {
    ltr: (rgb) => convert('rgb', 'hsv', rgb),
    rtl: (hsv) => convert('hsv', 'rgb' hsv),
  },
  deep: true,
})
```

We define a ref for each of the values, and then set up syncing for them. The transformers convert the value when a ref is changed, and the `deep` option makes the watchers watch for property changes as well as reassignments.

I made [a simple example of this on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nkwbrs?file=src%2FApp.vue).

### Standalone implementation

If you don't want to use a library, you can make a standalone equivalent.
The place to start would be [the index.ts file for `syncRef`](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/shared/syncRef/index.ts).

Below I present a very simple version.

First, we need a pausable watcher. I have whipped up a simple and minimal one that seems to do what is needed:

```js
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
import type { Ref, WatchCallback, WatchOptions, WatchStopHandle } from 'vue'

/**
 * Void function
 */
type Fn = () => void

export interface WatchPausableReturn {
  stop: WatchStopHandle

  /**
   * A ref indicating whether a pausable instance is active
   */
  isActive: Readonly<Ref<boolean>>

  /**
   * Temporarily pause the effect from executing
   */
  pause: Fn

  /**
   * Resume the effects
   */
  resume: Fn
}

/**
 * A minimal pausable watch.
 */
export function watchPausable<T>(
  source: Ref<T>,
  cb: WatchCallback<T, T | undefined>,
  options: WatchOptions
): WatchPausableReturn {
  const isActive = ref(true)

  const pause = () => {
    isActive.value = false
  }
  const resume = () => {
    isActive.value = true
  }

  const stop = watch(
    source,
    (...args) => {
      if (isActive.value) cb(...args)
    },
    options
  )

  return {
    stop,
    isActive,
    pause,
    resume,
  }
}
```

And then we can pretty much just use the code of VueUse's `syncRef` (I basically just changed the imports and pulled in some types):

```js
import type { Ref, WatchOptions } from 'vue'
import { watchPausable, type WatchPausableReturn } from './watchPausable'

export interface SyncRefOptions<L, R = L> {
  /**
   * Timing for monitoring changes, refer to WatchOptions for more details.
   * Unlike `watch()`, the default is set to `sync`
   *
   * @default 'sync'
   */
  flush?: WatchOptions['flush']
  /**
   * Watch deeply
   *
   * @default false
   */
  deep?: boolean
  /**
   * Sync values immediately
   *
   * @default true
   */
  immediate?: boolean

  /**
   * Custom transform function
   */
  transform?: {
    ltr?: (left: L) => R
    rtl?: (right: R) => L
  }
}

/**
 * Two-way refs synchronization.
 */
export function syncRef<L, R = L>(
  left: Ref<L>,
  right: Ref<R>,
  options: SyncRefOptions<L, R> = {}
) {
  const {
    flush = 'sync',
    deep = false,
    immediate = true,
    transform = {},
  } = options

  const watchers: WatchPausableReturn[] = []

  const transformLTR = transform.ltr ?? ((v) => v)
  const transformRTL = transform.rtl ?? ((v) => v)

  watchers.push(
    watchPausable(
      left,
      (newValue) => {
        watchers.forEach((w) => w.pause())
        right.value = transformLTR(newValue) as R
        watchers.forEach((w) => w.resume())
      },
      { flush, deep, immediate }
    )
  )

  watchers.push(
    watchPausable(
      right,
      (newValue) => {
        watchers.forEach((w) => w.pause())
        left.value = transformRTL(newValue) as L
        watchers.forEach((w) => w.resume())
      },
      { flush, deep, immediate }
    )
  )

  const stop = () => {
    watchers.forEach((w) => w.stop())
  }

  return stop
}
```

Testing it in [another StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ve8rms?file=src%2FApp.vue), it appears to work the same.

### Appendix

If this is something you are doing more than once, you can package it the use into a little helper function so that you don't need to manually define all the refs:

```js
function makeColorPair(initial: RgbColor) {
  const rgb = ref<RgbColor>(initial)
  const hsv = ref<HsvColor>(convert('rgb', 'hsv', rgb.value))

  const stop = syncRef(rgb, hsv, {
    transform: {
      ltr: (rgb) => convert('rgb', 'hsv', rgb),
      rtl: (hsv) => convert('hsv', 'rgb' hsv),
    },
    deep: true,
  })

  return {
    rgb,
    hsv,
    stop,
  }
}
```

And us it like this:

```js
const { rgb, hsv } = makeColorPair({ r:0, g:0, b:0 })
```

---

Be careful when using my little pausable watch function. There may be edge cases that it doesn't handle properly, especially when using non-sync flushing. You have been warned.

There are some "edge" cases that manifest with either implementation, such as using transformers that aren't the inverse of each other. For example, change the transformers in my examples to both just add something, and then fiddle around with the inputs.
When you change a property, the other object will have all its properties updated to be x more than those of the object you modified. Changing any property of the same object will then only affect the corresponding property of the other object. If you then modify a property of the other object, all the properties of the first object will be updated to be x more than the properties of the other object.
The behavior does make sense: the transformers are operating on the entire objects, not individual properties. When a change is made to an object, all the properties of the other object are updated. Once they are, further updates will only affect the properties that actually changed, as the others are set to the same values as before (because they are set relative to the first object's properties). This is why the first update affects all the properties, but not subsequent updates to the same object.
When the transformers are "symmetrical", this behavior does not manifest because the transformed values do not depend on the direction of the transform.

The really weird stuff happens when you change the `flush` option to something other than 'sync'...

---

VueUse is MIT licensed. I release all code in this answer under the same.